# Oracle Roles in VB.net Winforms application

Tags: sql, vb.net, winforms, oracle

I'm working with VB.Net and Oracle 11g connecting thru ODAC to build a desktop application, it should be pretty simple but I'm facing a situation.

I have my security roles and users defined on the Oracle Database, my intent is to show menus according to each role (i.e administrator should see every menu while user only the relevant menus) my question is how can this be accomplished?

I was creating a separate table with usernames and roles but I bet there's a better way for handling this. Willing to take all suggestions at this point

Comment: we did something similar to this by using a login form to get the user and security level (an int from 0 through 9 in our case), then using a `TreeView` object as a menu and only displaying menu options based on the security level of the user versus the pre-determined security level for each menu option we have coded in the program. if the users security is higher than the menu items security, it is displayed, and vice versa. hopefully that gives you something to work off of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use function `DBMS_SESSION.IS_ROLE_ENABLED` to get this information.

PL/SQL part would be like this

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION IsRoleGranted(RoleName IN VARCHAR2) RETURN Integer IS
BEGIN
    IF DBMS_SESSION.IS_ROLE_ENABLED(RoleName) THEN
        RETURN 1;
    ELSE
        RETURN 0;
    END IF;
END IsRoleGranted;
```

In VB.NET you an call the function like this:

```
  Dim cmd As OracleCommand
  Dim con As OracleConnection 
  con = New ...

  cmd = New OracleCommand("BEGIN IsRoleGranted(:role); END;" con)
  cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
  cmd.Parameters.Add("res", OracleDbType.Byte, ParameterDirection.ReturnValue)
  cmd.Parameters("res").DbType = DbType.Byte
  cmd.Parameters.Add("role", OracleDbType.Varchar2, ParameterDirection.Input).Value = "MYAPP_ADMIN"
  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
  AdminMenu.Visible = CByte(cmd.Parameters("res").Value) = 1
```

`DBMS_SESSION.IS_ROLE_ENABLED` is easier to use than query view `SESSION_ROLES` because it also covers hierarchy of roles, i.e. when a role is granted to another role.

Comment: I will take this this approach, will let you know the outcome

Answer (score 0):

Filling a table in Oracle with the active directory roles and users is an often used solution.
Oracle has a DBMS_LDAP package to access Active Directory so you can get a list of groups for your app.  I suggest a prefix for roles used in your app such as MyApp_admin, MyApp_user.

Then run a scheduled job to get the users that are in the groups and fill it into 
something like this pseudo code table

TABLE GROUP_USER (
ID NUMBER(9) primary key,
GROUP_NAME  VARCHAR2(250),
USER_NAME   VARCHAR2(250));

- This puts security at the enterprise level
- allows the possibility of single sign on using sys_context('USERENV','OS_USER')